# Formatting json object using php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to encode a json response using php, and having some trouble formatting it for use with ajax.

I'm basically trying to return an array of Rental objects, which each will include data for `book`, `student`, and `teacher`. Currently I'm using php to build objects like this...

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        $obj = array();

        // Build a book out of the results array, then push to the current object
        $book = new Book();
        $book->id = $row['book_id'];
        $book->title = $row['title'];
        $book->author = $row['author'];
        $book->ar_quiz = $row['ar_quiz'];
        $book->ar_quiz_pts = $row['ar_quiz_pts'];
        $book->book_level = $row['book_level'];
        $book->type = $row['type'];
        $book->teacher_id = $row['teacher_id'];
        array_push($obj, array('book' => $book));

        // Build a student out of the results array, then push it to the current objects
        $student = new Student();
        $student->id = $row['student_id'];
        $student->username = $row['student_username'];
        $student->nicename = $row['student_nicename'];
        $student->classroom_number = $row['classroom_number'];
        array_push($obj, array('student' => $student));


        // Build a teacher out of the results, push to current object
        $teacher = new Teacher();
        $teacher->id = $row['teacher_id'];
        $teacher->username = $row['teacher_username'];
        $teacher->nicename = $row['teacher_nicename'];
        array_push($obj, array('teacher' => $teacher));

        array_push($rentals, $obj);
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    return json_encode($rentals);
```

... building an $obj for each result, and then appending the whole $obj object to the end of $rentals, which is what I pass back in the end. Here is what the response looks like when I encode it to json:

```
   [  
      [  
        {  
           "book":{  
              "id":113,
              "title":"Book Test",
              "author":"Test Test Author",
              "ar_quiz":1,
              "ar_quiz_pts":"10.0",
              "book_level":"20.0",
              "type":"Fiction",
              "teacher_id":1
           }
        },
      {  
           "student":{  
              "id":2,
              "username":"studentnametest",
              "classroom_number":2,
              "nicename":"Student Name"
           }
      },
    ],
    ...
  ]
```

The problem here is that there is an extra {} around each of the `book`, `student`, and `teacher` objects, causing an extra step when trying to access in the javascript. For example, I think I have to use `data[0].[0].book.title`, when I really just want to be able to use `data[0].book.title`. How do I better structure this to fit my needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the additional array structure and you can simply change your array_push lines from

```
array_push($obj, array('book' => $book));
```

to

```
$obj['book'] =  $book;
```